# Tools like PVS-Studio for static code analysis in C projects?

Tags: c, static-analysis

I'm looking for some alternatives to the [PVS-Studio](http://pvs-studio.viva64.com) tool, in order to run some static code analysis in C projects. Do you guys have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't state what you need, nor platform (your nick suggests linux),
but I use(d) these in past with great impact on my code:

- **[Cppcheck](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/cppcheck)** (great eclipse plugin integration, its cpp but It does actually support C99 - plugin is called cppcheclipse)
- **Sparse**  (can be inegrated into eclipse by using "external tools")
- **[Splint](http://www.splint.org/)** (eclipse CDT has plugin)
- **Codan**  (internal part of eclipse)
- **[Intel SSA](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/static-security-analysis/)** (I believe this can be accessed from Intel Compaser or Parallel studio, both of which provide free non-commercial like license and official Intel eclipse integration plugin)

All of these can be integrated at the same time into eclipse (using plugins, "run external tools" ar internally) and provide real time checking and analysis within **Eclipse CDT IDE for linux programmers**.

If you want more, there is alsa awesome set of tools in **Frama-C**.

These are best free tools (not necessarily opensource or free for commercial use) for static analysis I know of and they really make nice synergy with eclipse. 
Sorry for advertising eclipse btw, except for Codan tools, these are accessible by other means (cppcheck provides simple GUI I believe, and others are all accessible from shell).

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what features you're looking for, but you can check out [Vigilant Sentry](http://www.vigilantsw.com/sentry/) and see if it meets your needs. It does static analysis of C and C++ programs, and has a plugin system for developing your own custom checks.

Comment: Actually, i was looking for a cheaper solution or open-source one. :D